# Spark - there is no type "Dataframe" in Java

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am going through  [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/index.html#DataFrame=org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5Borg.apache.spark.sql.Row%5D) and [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/java/index.html) . I clearly see the type"Dataframe" is defined for scala and not for Java. Does that mean type "Dataframe" is not *technically* supported but rather use Dataset[T] insetad ?

And also, from [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html) , please share inputs about what does it mean - Does that signify the same fact Java doesnt have the construct for dataframe ?

> Scala      Dataset[T] & DataFrame (alias for Dataset[Row])

> Java       Dataset[T]

Comment: All Scala classes are visible to Java and vice versa. Have you added the spark and scala libraries to your Maven/Gradle/SBT? E.g. for Maven to your pom.xml file.

Comment: I did , i was referring to the javadoc and scaladoc and also the other question wrt DataFrame (alias for Dataset[Row]) - it is not mentioned in Java

Comment: @DannyVarod `DataFrame` is a type alias, not a class.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I know, for `Dataset[Row]`, forgot that java can't see these though.

Comment: @Nag why not use a scala class in your code? It will still compile into your jar, however, you will be able to use all the scala "goodies" such as lambdas, implicits, typetags, spark-encoders etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has no concept of a type alias, so in Java, you would need to use

```
Dataset<org.apache.spark.sql.Row>
```

to refer to a `Dataframe`.

Comment: as simple as that. thanks . so,  no "DataFrame" construct in java